# eslint warns about a file being ignored even though I specifically ignored it. Can I disable this?

Tags: javascript, eslint

In my `eslintrc.js` I have the following ignore patterns:

```
...
ignorePatterns: [
  'bin',
  'src/modules/**/*.js',
  'test',
  'build_util'
],
...
```

When linting I run this:

```
eslint src/**/*.js
```

Everything looks good except I get this warning:

```
/Users/me/repos/my-project/src/modules/server.js
  0:0  warning  File ignored because of a matching ignore pattern. Use "--no-ignore" to override
```

According to the documentation it says:

> This message occurs because ESLint is unsure if you wanted to actually lint the file or not.

Uhhh what? How does that make sense? I very specifically told eslint to ignore all js files in that directory. Why is it giving me this warning?

What am I misunderstanding here? How do I turn off warnings like this without turning off all warnings?

Comment: My best guess is that this arises from the overlap between the pattern you passed to eslint and the ignore pattern. Consider: If you explicitly invoke `eslint foo.js` and `foo.js` is an ignored pattern, what’s the expected behavior? I understand why this emits a warning. I also understand why the warning is annoying.

Comment: I'd guess if you use `eslint src/` it'll be fine. Right now your *shell* is doing the expansion, so explicitly passing files to ESLint you've told it it's supposed to be ignoring. Just pass the directory, it already lints only .js files by default.